# R: Get quantmod's chartSeries and AddTA to not show last value

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

When using chartSeries, by default it also shows on the top left of the plot the last value. Is there any way to prevent it from doing it?

When adding a new TA with addTA, you can avoid the last value on the plot by setting the argument legend = "", but only if you're making a new plot for the TA. If the TA is on a previously plotted graphic, it'll show the last value regardless of what you put in the legend argument.

```
getSymbols ("AAPL", src = "google")
chartSeries(AAPL)
```

What can I use here to prevent it from printing the last value on the plot?

```
addTA(EMA(Cl(AAPL)), on = 1, legend = "")
```

This still prints the last value on the top left of the plot. The weird part is that it doesn't do it if you're plotting on a new plot like this:

```
addTA(EMA(Cl(AAPL)), legend = "")
```

Is it like this by default, or is there something I can do to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last value is shown by default (yes, annoyingly).  You'll likely have to modify the source code to remove the last number showing in `addTA`.

I don't use `addTA`, but rather `add_TA` and `chart_Series`, because I think they look much better (second generation charts for `quantmod`).  Here is a solution that removes the last number from showing for the `add_TA` version.  But you must be willing to modify the source code.

In add_TA, you'll need to modify approximately lines 56-60 of the source:

Replace the `text.exp`, which is this:

```
# this is inside add_TA:
if (is.na(on)) {
    plot_object$add_frame(ylim = c(0, 1), asp = 0.15)
    plot_object$next_frame()
    text.exp <- expression(text(x = c(1, 1 + strwidth(name)), 
                                y = 0.3, labels = c(name, round(last(xdata[xsubset]), 
                                                                5)), col = c(1, col), adj = c(0, 0), cex = 0.9, 
                                offset = 0, pos = 4))
    plot_object$add(text.exp, env = c(lenv, plot_object$Env),
```

with these modifications:

```
if (is.na(on)) {
    plot_object$add_frame(ylim = c(0, 1), asp = 0.15)
    plot_object$next_frame()
    text.exp <- expression(text(x = c(strwidth(name)), # <- affects label on the subchart
                            y = 0.3, labels = name, col = c(col), adj = c(0), cex = 0.9, 
                            offset = 1, pos = 4))
     plot_object$add(text.exp, env = c(lenv, plot_object$Env), 
                expr = TRUE)
```

...
and assign this modified code to a new variable, called say `add_TA.mine`:

```
add_TA.mine <- function (x, order = NULL, on = NA, legend = "auto", yaxis = list(NULL, 
                                                                  NULL), col = 1, taType = NULL, ...) 
{
  lenv <- new.env()
  lenv$name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  lenv$plot_ta <- function(x, ta, on, taType, col = col, ...) {
    xdata <- x$Env$xdata 
    ....
     [all the code for the rest of the function with modifications]....

           }
    }
    plot_object
}
```

Now, just run the code with the modified function

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")

environment(add_TA.mine) <- environment(get("add_TA", envir = asNamespace("quantmod")))
assignInNamespace(x = "add_TA", value = add_TA.mine, ns = "quantmod")


chart_Series(AAPL, subset = "2017")
add_TA(RSI(Cl(AAPL)))
quantmod:::add_TA(RSI(Cl(AAPL)))
```

You can see the last value is no longer printed:

[image]

(You could make the same kinds of changes in the old `addTA` code (perhaps via `chartSeries` if you really want to stick to the old plots)

If you're happy with the changes, and want to make them permament in `add_TA`, you can recompile the `quantmod` source code yourself with your modifications (i.e. you need to download the quantmod source code and recompile the package) .  If you make a mess of things you can always redownload the original `quandmod` source code again.

Comment: Thanks, but there was no need to modify the source code in the end. The way it works now, though the second generation chart add_TA does print the last value when creating a new chart below your previously plotted data, at least it doesn't do it when you're adding the TA on one of the pre existing charts by using the on = argument. Since I tend to add a lot of notations and references (usually in xts plots), I needed a way for chartSeries to not fill the screen with last values for every notations or indicator I added to the chart. Just knowing this second generation charts helps a lot. Thanks